# how do i write in sas a filter that subtracts dates

Tags: date, filter, sas, proc-sql, datastep

Hello Stackoverflow community... hope you can help with this sas question.

I need to create a filter for a table which gives back only those records that are active from last year forward.

I would like to obtain something like :

```
data want;
set have;
where expire_date >= current(date) - 1year:
run;
```

the format of the expire_date column is 03MAY2022 (date9. format)... I tried to transform the date into a number and then subtracting 365, but i guess there is a better solution.

can someone illuminate me?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you are searching for the INTNX() function:
https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.2/lefunctionsref/p10v3sa3i4kfxfn1sovhi5xzxh8n.htm#n1lchasgjah7ran0z2wlmsbfwdx2
For example:

```
data a;
  format num_date num_date_minus_year DATE9.;
  char_date="03MAY2022";
  num_date = inputn (char_date, "DATE9.");
  num_date_minus_year = intnx ('YEAR', num_date, -1, "SAME");
  put num_date= num_date_minus_year=;
run;
```

Output:

```
num_date=03MAY2022 num_date_minus_year=03MAY2021
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current date using the DATE() function.

Do you want one YEAR or 365 days?

To use a date interval use the INTNX() function.

```
where expire_date >= intnx('year',date(),-1,'same') ;
```

To use a fixed number of days just subtract the number.

```
where expire_date >= date() - 365 ;
```